# How to run a JavaScript snippet only if an iframe exists on the current page?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, iframe, youtube

I want to do a modification to YouTube embedded iframes to improve the Lighthouse score but I cannot make the if statement work:

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')){
function init() {
    var vidDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    for (var i=0; i<vidDefer.length; i++) {
    if(vidDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
    vidDefer[i].setAttribute('src',vidDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
    } } }
    window.onload = init;
    function parseJSAtOnload() {
        var element = document.createElement("script");
        element.src = "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/yts/jsbin/player_ias-vflRCamp0/en_US/base.js";
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        }
        if (window.addEventListener)
            window.addEventListener("load", parseJSAtOnload, false);
        else if (window.attachEvent)
            window.attachEvent("onload", parseJSAtOnload);
        else window.onload = parseJSAtOnload;
}
```

I only want to run this snippet if there exists an iframe element on the current page and not always. This way I could embed the code on every page of my website, no matter of the content. With the above code it still gets active always. How to make it work only on pages with an iframe?

I see this error in the developer console on all pages, even for ones without without any iframe elements:

> GET
> https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/yts/jsbin/player_ias-vflRCamp0/en_US/base.js
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Comment: Your code should work as long as there are no other `iframe` elements. I mean, your condition will pass for any `iframe` element in the DOM. Is that the case? If so, you'll have to filter your elements.

Comment: But even on a page without an iframe I still see this error in the developer console: GET https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/yts/jsbin/player_ias-vflRCamp0/en_US/base.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Comment: Have you run this code on your own development server in a page that has no analytics, social media buttons or third-party integration?

Comment: @Peleke well, that is another thing. Your URL seems to have no associated resources. Is some kind of authentication required to access that file? Or is it possible that it does not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName()` returns an empty collection.
Empty HTMLCollections are objects, which reduce to the primitive `true`. (I know, JavaScript is crazy...)

So, `if( document.getElementsByTagName( 'no-such-element' ) )` will always evaluate to `true`.

You want:

```js
if( document.getElementsByTagName( 'iframe' ).length > 0 ) {
//...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works as desired.